# how to put the node:link token in the html a label?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

i have installed the views and token module. i add a views field 'Node:Link'  and check the 'exclude from display' option for the 'node:link' field and set the field first in the field order,now i want to overrite a views field.

i put this `<a href="[view_node]"> more >>  </a>` in the `rewrite the output of this field` text box. but it can't work? `[view_node]` is the `Node:Link` token, how to make the `more>>` link ok? thank you

Comment: this would work but you shouldn't check the 'exclude from display' box if you're doing it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views has a built in way to make text link to other pages with tokens. I would use that instead of putting the anchor tag in the rewrite section. It's titled, "Output this field as a link"

If you're on Drupal 6 and you just want to link the field to it's node then just check the box "Link this field to it's node"

Comment: i know what's your said, but the more >> link is to another place. not the Link this field to it's node

Comment: Use a Global Text field and then use Output this field as a link

Answer (score 1):

In the `Node:Link` field, enter `more` in `Text to display:` text box.

No need to put anchor tag just type `[view_node]` in the rewrite the output of this field text box.